# How to display a table row separately on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to click a row in the table and edit that specific row. My goal is to have it open into a form where it's editable. I can't seem to get it to output the row in a form. I've tried a few different things. I have the basic set up here on [codepen](http://codepen.io/tetonhiker/pen/LbXpeL). How can I get it to show that specific row inside a page overlay and a form? I've tried inserting it into an input but that doesn't work.

Do I need to call the $(".rowEditData") differently to separate out each column, if so how do I do that exactly?

```js
function openOverlay(){
  document.getElementById("pageOverlay").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function closeOverlay(){
  document.getElementById("pageOverlay").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
// show row data to be edited or view single row
$(".rowEditData").click(function(index){
  triggerEditOverlay();
});
//popup overlay function for editing row
function triggerEditOverlay(){
  // Clear the div
  /*here you were using a ; after .html() not showing the rest of your 'form'*/
  $("#pageOverlay").empty();  
  html = "<div id='editableTableDiv'>" + $(".rowEditData").html() + "<input type='button' class='mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored' value='Close' onclick='closeOverlay()'></div>";
  $("#pageOverlay").html(html);
  // open div overlay
  openOverlay();
} // end popup overlay fn
```

```css
#pageOverlay {visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25); z-index: 99;}
#pageOverlay div {padding: 1%; width: 30%; height:80%; margin: 100px; margin-left:35%; background-color: rgb(255,255,255);}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageOverlay"></div>
<table id="dataTable" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Shape Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 401px;">Shape Name</th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Number Edges: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 436px;">Number Edges</th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Sum of Interior Angles: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 638px;">Sum of Interior Angles</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7924" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Hexagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7923" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7930" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">180</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7931" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">360</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7932" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">5</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7933" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7934" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">10</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">1440</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7925" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Octagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">8</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7922" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">pentagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7926" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Pentagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7920" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7927" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7928" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7921" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">trapezoid</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7919" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">triangle</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7929" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Triangle</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` or `$(this)` to refer to the element being clicked on. Using `$(".rowEditData").html()` will only use the first match. I'd also reduce the code you have to the following which removes your inline event handler and uses event delegation for the close/hide function.

```js
// show row data to be edited or view single row
$(".rowEditData").click(function() {
  html = "<div id='editableTableDiv'>" + $(this).html() + "<input type='button' class='mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored' value='Close'></div>";
  $("#pageOverlay").html(html).show();
});

$(document).on('click', '#editableTableDiv input', function() {
  $("#pageOverlay").hide();
})
```

```css
#pageOverlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 99;
}
#pageOverlay div {
  padding: 1%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 100px;
  margin-left: 35%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageOverlay"></div>
<table id="dataTable" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Shape Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 401px;">Shape Name</th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Number Edges: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 436px;">Number Edges</th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Sum of Interior Angles: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 638px;">Sum of Interior Angles</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7924" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Hexagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7923" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7930" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">180</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7931" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">360</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7932" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">5</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7933" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7934" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">10</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">1440</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7925" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Octagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">8</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7922" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">pentagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7926" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Pentagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7920" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7927" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7928" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7921" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">trapezoid</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7919" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">triangle</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7929" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Triangle</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I then get the row to output into form fields? Like separate each column into it's own field on the form?

Comment: `$(this).find('td').eq(0).html()` would select the first table cell's html, `eq(1)` the second, and so on.

Comment: One more question, how could I then save the data the user edits? I know I need to an ajax call, but how do I only save the data in the overlay and not everything in the table? I added a save button and creating a new function to save, but just not sure how to only capture the data I edited and not the whole table.

Comment: That answer would be too long for the comments section. Consider creating a new question.

Comment: If you have time please look at my new question and give me any hints, tips, or suggestions you can. I would greatly appreciate it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152039/how-to-save-edited-data-from-a-table-back-to-the-database-with-jquery