# How to save edited data from a table back to the database with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a table where users can click on the row and then edit the row. I want to now be able to save it back to the database. How can I do this? I'm just not sure how to create the ajax call to run it.

```js
// overlay functions
function openOverlay(){
  document.getElementById("pageOverlay").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function closeOverlay(){
  document.getElementById("pageOverlay").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
// show row data to be edited or view single row
$(".rowEditData").click(function() {
     html = "<div id='editableTableDiv'><label class='editRowLabel'>Shape Name:</label> <input type='text' class='mdl-textfield__input' name='shapeName' value="+ $(this).find('td').eq(0).html() + "><br><label class='editRowLabel'>Number Edges:</label> <input type='text' class='mdl-textfield__input' name='numberEdges' value="+ $(this).find('td').eq(1).html() + "><br><label class='editRowLabel'>Sum of Interior Angles:</label> <input type='text' class='mdl-textfield__input' name='sumAngles' value="+ $(this).find('td').eq(2).html() + "><br><br><input type='button' class='mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored' value='Save' onclick='saveNewRowData()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' class='mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored' value='Close' onclick='closeOverlay()'></div>";
  $("#pageOverlay").html(html).show();
  openOverlay();
});

function saveNewRowData(){
    shapeName = $("input[name=shapeName]").val();
    numberEdges = $("input[name=numberEdges]").val();
    sumAngles = $("input[name=sumAngles]").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "someURLhere.php",
        data: data,
        type: "post"
    });
}
```

```css
#pageOverlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 99;
}
#pageOverlay div {
  padding: 1%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 100px;
  margin-left: 35%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.editRowLabel {
  font-weight:bold; 
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageOverlay"></div>
<table id="dataTable" class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Shape Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 401px;">Shape Name</th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Number Edges: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 436px;">Number Edges</th>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Sum of Interior Angles: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 638px;">Sum of Interior Angles</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7924" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Hexagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7923" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7930" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">180</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7931" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">360</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7932" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">5</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7933" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">6</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">120</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7934" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">10</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">1440</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7925" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Octagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">8</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7922" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">pentagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7926" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Pentagon</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7920" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7927" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7928" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Square</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7921" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">trapezoid</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">4</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData odd" value="7919" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">triangle</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rowEditData even" value="7929" role="row">
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric sorting_1">Triangle</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">3</td>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">null</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you know how to handle the request on the server side from the Ajax request?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to handle it. I know I need to use ajax to save it back to the db, but just not sure how to set up that function

Comment: your url is empty.  What are you saving it to,  a php page, web service, what?  Do you want it to go back as a posted form or JSON?

Comment: I updated the ajax function and now get the correct values. Now I just need to create the ajax call and the php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with that works. I just use a php script to then save the data to the database.

```
    function saveNewRowData(){
      shapeName = $("input[name=shapeName]").val();
      numberEdges = $("input[name=numberEdges]").val();
      sumAngles = $("input[name=sumAngles]").val();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "saveNewData.php",
          data: {shapeName: shapeName, numberEdges: numberEdges, sumAngles: sumAngles},
          success: function(response){

          }
      });
    }
```

Comment: I was trying to do something like this awhile ago. Glad I was able to find this answer.

Answer (score 2):

- One thing  you  would  need connection to the database
- you will  need  to ajax  each row

  $(document).ready(function() 
  {`$('#btn').click(function(e)` {

  ```
      e.preventDefault();

      $('#yourTable tr').each(function(i, tr) {

          var postData = {
              CoumnName : $('.row-class').val(),
              ColumnName : $('.row-class').val()
          }

          console.log(postData);

          $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "/your url",
              data: postData
          })
          .done(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              alert("Success!");
          })
          .fail(function(x, status, error) {
              alert("Error: " + error);
          });
      });
  });
  ```

  });